# Acronyms - Best practice to use during the text and create acronym page

Tags: packages, best-practices, acronyms

I'm starting writing my PhD thesis in LaTeX however since I'm still at the beginning of the PhD I'm writing some pieces at the introduction, other at methods, sometimes the other way around. When I find an acronym I want to use I just write it up normally, for instance World Health Organisation (WHO) and then use WHO later on. However, since I'm not following a normal order, I may end up using WHO before definning it.

I create my acronym page the following way:

```
\begin{acronym}[AWGN]
\acro{WHO}{World Health Organisation}
\end{acronym}
```

I would like to know what is the best practice in these cases. I've seen so many different packages that I'm not sure which one would be more appropriate.

Looking forward to some feedback.

Comment: With the glossaries package, you can define the acronym, then use the shorthand command anywhere you want and glossaries will figure out where you used it first. Glossaries will then (according to how you set it up) automatically print the long form at the first occurrence of the command and the abbreviation any time after this.

Comment: Thank you! It's waht I was looking for. I though it only printed the long format every time. @brian-ammon If you want to transform your comment into a response I will be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package provides the command

```
\newacronym[〈key-val list〉]{〈label〉}{〈abbrv〉}{〈long〉}
```

which creates an acronym that can be called via `\gls{〈label〉}` and which will produce “〈long〉 (〈abbrv〉)” on first use and “〈abbrv〉” on subsequent uses. You can therefore use `\gls{〈label〉}` anywhere in your document and `glossaries` will automatically determine the position of its first occurrence, when it will print the long form as well as the abbreviation.

The way this works is extremely customizable; please refer to [Section 13 “Acronyms”](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf#chapter.13) of the `glossaries` manual to see how to adjust the formatting as well as behaviour.